# Determining file inclusion for files

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to determine how many times require_once or any other inclusion method is being called on a specific file?  I had an infinite loop issue with some kind of inclusion error, it's gone now, but I'd like to be certain I'm not excessively including files.

Comment: `*_once()` methods only once! For `include` and `require` I don't know, but guess you can set some kind of counter inside external scripts.

Comment: I know it only actually includes once, but I was wondering if you could determine how many times it's being called.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a text search software that will show me all occurrences of the page name across all the files on your site.  This would return any require, include, etc that references it, and the file it is in.  Most good IDE's will do this.

Answer (score 0):

My simple idea using text file on server... for example

### extern.php

```
<?php

  $file = 'count.txt';

  $v = 1;
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
    $v = fgets($fp) + 1;
    fclose($fp);
    }
  $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
  fputs($fp, $v);
  fclose($fp);
  echo "counter: $v";

?>
```

### index.php

```
<?php

  include('extern.php');

?>
```

This will print out "include-counter" on every include of `extern.php` file. Result has been stored in text file `count.txt`.

Note: Don't use relative file path (like I did in example) because script may be called from different directories.